# Creating and changing splash screen in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, splash-screen

I have following Code:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CreateSplashScrn));
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();

    OpenSplashScrn();
    ChangeSplashScrnMessageText("String");

    public void CreateSplashScrn()
    {
        splash = new SplashScreen(this);
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    }

    public void OpenSplashScrn()
    {
        splash.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new Action(() => { splash.Show(); }));
    }

    public void ChangeSplashScrnMessageText(string messageText)
    {
        splash.messageLabel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new Action(() => { splash.messageLabel.Content = messageText; }));
    }
```

However, this returns a Null Reference Exception at OpenSplashScrn().
How can I open this in another thread and change the Label content?
Is this possible over a Task?

Comment: why do you want to open splash screen in another thread?

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT open splach screen in background thread and perform the long running initialization in UI thread.

You should open splash screen in UI thread and perform the long running initialization in non UI thread.

```
var splash = new SplashScreen(this);
splash.Show(); 

Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Initialize));
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();


public void Initialize()
{
    //move your long running logic from your app here..
    ChangeSplashScrnMessageText("Initialization Started");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    ChangeSplashScrnMessageText("Initialize finished");
}

public void ChangeSplashScrnMessageText(string messageText)
{
    splash.messageLabel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new Action(() => { splash.messageLabel.Content = messageText; }));
}
```

**EDIT: Why you should not open Splash Screen in another thread?**

Because it complicates things a log and in 99% there is no reason to do so. You can have multiple windows running in single thread and still perform some long running task in the background.

I guess, that in your main window you are trying to perform the long running task in UI thread. Just move it to background thread...

Comment: Thanks but how would this work when starting it from the UI?

Comment: @Jackson30: I've written the example assuming you start it from UI thread. Describe better in your question what do you expect from user's POV

Comment: Sorry I meant starting the splash screen from another thread than the UI thread

Comment: @CameronMacFarland: Both threads are UI threads in his example, not in mine. Even assuming you refered to his example, all my claims are valid, aren't they? Although it's probably technically possible to run UI in background thread (IsBackground=True), I would differentiate the two, since UI thread running in background looks like oxymoron.

Comment: @Jackson30: I said you: you should not start splash screen from another thread than UI thread.

Comment: Let's move the discussion to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100991/discussion-between-liero-and-jackson30):